# If - else - Localstorage dont work / cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, if-statement

I want to check if its the first app start. I run my app via xcode on my iphone on usb. But everytime i close the app on iphone and start it again with clicking the icon on my phone - like a restart - it dont recognize that the app was startet before. What i am doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("applaunch")) {
        window.localStorage.getItem("callstatus");

    }else{
        //Local storage is not set, hence first time launch. set the local storage item
        window.localStorage.setItem('applaunch',1);
        window.localStorage.setItem("vipstatus", "0");
        window.localStorage.setItem("callstatus", "0");
    }

    function generateUUID() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,function(c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d/16);
            return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x7|0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        return uuid.toUpperCase();
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem("username",generateUUID());

    var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
    var vipstatus = window.localStorage.getItem("vipstatus");
    var callstatus = window.localStorage.getItem("callstatus");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://www.bla.com/action.php',
        data: {
            data: {"username": username, "vipstatus" : vipstatus, "callstatus" : callstatus},
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Everytime i restart the app on the phone (NOT VIA XCODE BUILDING AGAIN) its making a new entry in my db - see ajax.

Comment: Your AJAX call isn't inside an `if` that tests whether it's the first time.

Comment: Ok, but what did you expected? In the `if (localStorage.getItem("applaunch")) { ... }` there is no `return` whatsoever to prevent the subsequent ajax call?

Comment: Why are you calling `getItem("callstatus")` without storing the result anywhere?

Comment: @Barmar - I thought it works like this - when the app is already been lunched before get the item "callstatus" which is set at the first lunch. is that wrong? The code on this not complete just want to wrote anything in.

Comment: That's correct. But if you get the item, you should do something with it, like put it in a variable so you can use it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable that says whether it's the first time. Then only make the AJAX call when the variable is true.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var first_time;
    if (localStorage.getItem("applaunch")) {
        first_time = false;
    }else{
        //Local storage is not set, hence first time launch. set the local storage item
        window.localStorage.setItem('applaunch',1);
        window.localStorage.setItem("vipstatus", "0");
        window.localStorage.setItem("callstatus", "0");
        first_time = true;
    }

    function generateUUID() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,function(c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d/16);
            return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x7|0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        return uuid.toUpperCase();
    }

    if (first_time) {    
        window.localStorage.setItem("username",generateUUID());
    }

    var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
    var vipstatus = window.localStorage.getItem("vipstatus");
    var callstatus = window.localStorage.getItem("callstatus");

    if (first_time) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://www.bla.com/action.php',
            data: {
                data: {"username": username, "vipstatus" : vipstatus, "callstatus" : callstatus},
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @barmar. Dont be mad, im still learning, i dont just simple copy paste - i try to understand :) Thanks for your help.